# How to save JSON data in List? Angular 8

Tags: html, json, angular, typescript, list

i have following ts:

```
list: any;

this.service.gets(this.id).subscribe(data => {
       if (data) {
         this.list= data.x;
      } else {
        console.log('No x available');
      }
    });
```

i have following json:

```
  "ware": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "b",
      "number": "30",
      "x": 20,
    },
     {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "b",
      "number": "30",
      "x": 25,
    }
  ],
```

I want to save the x of the objects in "ware" in list. I tried it like above in the ts. But it didn't work. I get only an undefined when i try:
i have following html:

```
{{list[0]}}
```

I hope you can help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data.ware.map(item => item.x)
```